# Passing a float value from SQL to WebSpace giving unexpected value

Tags: php, sql, floating-point

**Here is an example of my data:**

```
Id,Name,Price
121,Jelly beans,6.79
122,Banana milkshake powder,8.31
123,Edam Cheese,18.73
124,Hairnet,8.05
```

When I extract it using an SQL query and pass it through to my webspace using this code:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   echo "<p>"."Name: ".$row['Name']." Price: ".$row['Price']." Total Sales: ".$row['Total Sales']."</p>"; 
}
```

**It's displayed like this:**

```
Name: Jelly beans Price: 6.789999961853 Total Sales: 8427
Name: Banana milkshake powder Price: 8.3100004196167 Total Sales: 18054
Name: Edam Cheese Price: 18.729999542236 Total Sales: 12771
Name: Hairnet Price: 8.0500001907349 Total Sales: 4594
```

Now usually I'd say is their any way to format my code to only display Price to 2 decimal places? As this would usually suffice. However it is giving an invalid Price for some of the values.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

```
number_format($row['price'], 2, ',', '.');
```